# SQL count occurrence in the dataset, but the variable value coud swap

Tags: sql, count, sas, reverse, occurrence-typing

I have a question about my **SAS on demand, sql** procedure.

The original dataset looks like this:

```
Obs    From    To    
------------------------
1      A         B
2      A         C
3      B         A
4      C         A
5      E         C
6      C         A
```

The thing is I **don't care what appears in From and To,** I only care about how many times both of them exist.

I need an output like:

```
A B occured(no matter what order): 2
A C occured(no matter what order): 3
C E occured(no matter what order): 1
```

Comment: Yes yes just done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL

`SELECT CONCAT(A, B) as CAB, COUNT(*) from(SELECT greatest(A,B) as A, least(A,B) as B FROM original_table)s GROUP BY CAB`

gets the results you want.

Comment: Thanks though my sas studio doesn't have concat

Comment: omg  thank you so much!!! I used your code and combine with the upper coed and found it worked!!!!

Comment: @UnknownSTATStudent . . . Why would you accept this answer over Mureinik's which is simpler (no subquery), works in more databases (doesn't use an alias for `group by`), and posted was over half an hour earlier?  I'm just curious.

Comment: Because the subquery is more efficient in most cases with most SQL engines as long as you have an index on the where clause predicates. You always think about SQL efficiency - I've been doing that for more than thirty years.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention what [rdbms](/questions/tagged/rdbms) you're using, but most have `least` and `greatest` functions which you could use so you always get the "smaller" value of the left. E.g.:

```
SELECT   LEAST(lista, listb) || '&' || GREATEST(lista, listb), COUNT(*)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY LEAST(lista, listb), GREATEST(lista, listb)
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks so much for replying my question! My variables are character variables(like airport names), can I still use those methods? Thanks!

Comment: @MichelleShen As I noted, you didn't mention what RDBMS you're using, so I can't say for sure, but generally, if your RDBMS has these functions, they should be overloaded for any type you can sort by (i.e., have in the `order by` clause). `char`s and `varchar`s are definitely such types.

Answer (score 2):

Not all databases support `least()` and `greatest()`.  You can write this as:

```
select (case when lista < listb then lista else listb end),
       (case when lista < listb then listb else lista end),
       count(*)
from t
group by (case when lista < listb then lista else listb end),
         (case when lista < listb then listb else lista end);
```

If you want this as one string:

```
select ((case when lista < listb then lista else listb end) || '&' ||
        (case when lista < listb then listb else lista end)
       ),
       count(*)
from t
group by (case when lista < listb then lista else listb end),
         (case when lista < listb then listb else lista end);
```

Comment: omg  thank you so much!!! I used your code and combine with the upper coed and found it worked!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you are using SAS here is the syntax you can use.

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
  select min(from,to) as first
       , max(from,to) as second
       , count(*) as count
  from have 
  group by 1,2
;
quit;
```